# UI5 Data Binding from an Array of Objects (JS View)

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5

I am trying to bind Data to my table .

My Data looks like this :[image]

And relevant parts of my Code :

from View :

```
var innerTable2 = new sap.m.Table(this.createId("innerTable2"), {
        columns: [
            new sap.m.Column({
                header: new sap.m.Label({
                    text: " Header Text"
                })
            }),
            new sap.m.Column({
                header: new sap.m.Label({
                    text: " Header Text 2"
                })
            })
        ]
    }).addStyleClass("table-result");
```

from Controller :

```
// creating path for the property I need
var path_STOFFTYP = "{" + elementId + "/stoff/STOFFTYP}";
var oInnerTemplate2 = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
    cells: [
        new sap.m.Text({
            text: "test"
        }),
        new sap.m.Text({
            text: path_STOFFTYP
        })
    ]
});
//here binding template to table 
this.byId("innerTable2").setModel(oModel).bindItems("/results/rs999", oInnerTemplate2);
```

If I leave   the `path_STOFFTYP` as it is now, I don't recieve any data.

If I make it  only "stoff" it shows `[object Object]`  as much as the length of `stoff` array.

What I know, for sure is , the property  "stoff" has at least 1 and maximum 65 different  elements ( depends to the selected  item. its dynamic)

If I change the   var `path_STOFFTYP` to `"{" + elementId + "/stoff/0/STOFFTYP}";`

It shows the value of "Wirkstoff". Which is  correct, however I don't want to create 60 different properties.

My Question : How can I manage to get all values of the property "STOFFTYP" from the array "stoff"  ?  I want to bind it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you are trying to do.

But your Binding is wrong stoff is an array inside the results/rs999 array. So it is array in array.

Your template should only use relative bindings so

```
path_STOFFTYP = "{STOFFTYP}";
```

And then you should bind your items dynamically to some kind of this path:

```
/here binding template to table 
this.byId("innerTable2").setModel(oModel).bindItems("/results/rs999/"+elementId+"/stoff", oInnerTemplate2);
```